# Replace a string with an image in java?

Tags: java, string, spring

Is there any way by which i can replace a text with an image? Can i tweak any of the string Util method in order to do so like **replace**, **replaceAll** or anything else? I tried a lot of things but could not do it. I know it is an idiotic kinds question but give it a go.

```
String string = "This is an |IMAGE|";
( string.contains("IMAGE") ? string.replace("|IMAGE|", *what to do here*) : string  );
```

I want to replace the |IMAGE| with an image from my system.

The output should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Please give more information (clearly) as to what you are wanting.

Comment: Is this for a GUI program?

Comment: maybe, but it uses java.

Comment: @v0ld3m0rt I think I need to refresh my brain - your question still does not make sense to me.

Comment: Can you photoshop and example of exactly what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: Is this a web application ? Do you want to add an image for example `google.com/image.jpg` where ever the String is `IMAGE` ?

Comment: yeah @sharonHwk. you got me.

Comment: Is this for a website, or a desktop program?

Comment: webapp, to be precise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `String` cannot contain an image. It is strictly a sequence of characters.

But if your string is actually a piece of HTML text you could put in an `img` tag. For example:

```
This is an <img src="url/of/the/image">
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to replace a String with an image. It doesn't really work like that.

That's what the `alt` in html is for. If an image cannot be retrieve, a message shows instead.

```
This is an <img src="someImage" alt="[ IMAGE ]"/>
```

[image]

```
<html>
    <body>
    This is an <img src="fblfhalf" alt="[ IMAGE ]"/>
    <body>
</html>
```

If the path was correct, an image would appear

```
This is an <img src="average.png" alt="[ IMAGE ]"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pure string cannot display image.

But if you have access to Swing GUI you can opt out to using JLabel class that is in simple words is label with image glued together.

You can check [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) on JLabel on Oracle site.